# Python - How to scrape Tr/Td table data using 'requests & BeautifulSoup'

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm new to programming. I'm trying out my first Web Crawler program that will help me with my job. I'm trying to build a program that will scrape tr/td table data from a web page, but am having difficulties succeeding. Here is what I have so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def start(url):
    source_code = requests.get(url).text
    soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
    for table_data in soup.find_all('td', {'class': 'sorting_1'}):
        print(table_data)

start('http://www.datatables.net/')
```

My goal is to print out each line and then export it to an excel file.

Thank you,
-Cire

Comment: it's not a bad start, what part doesn't work?

Comment: I can't seem to get any data from this script. It just says "process finished with exit code 0".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My recommendation is that if you are new to Python, play with things via the iPython notebook (interactive prompt) to get things working first and to get a feel for things before you try writing a script or a function. On the plus side all variables will stick around and it is much easier to see what is going on.

From the screen shot here, you can see immediately that the `find_all` function is not finding anything. An empty lists `[]` is being returned. By using `ipython` you can easily try other variants of a function on a previously defined variable. For example, the `soup.find_all('td')`.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation William. I will definitely mess around with it.

Comment: Ah! That definitely helps! Thank you very much William! :)

Comment: Hi @cire if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the source of http://www.datatables.net, I do not see *any* instances of the text `sorting_1`, so I wouldn't expect a search for all table cells of that `class` to return anything.

Perhaps that `class` appeared on a different URL associated with the *DataTables* website, in which case you would need to use that URL in your code. It's also possible that that `class` only appears after certain *JavaScript* has been run client-side (i.e. after certain actions with the sample tables, perhaps), and not on the initially loaded page.

I'd recommend starting with tags you know are on the initial page (seen by looking at the page source in your browser).

For example, currently, I can see a `div` with `class="content"`. So the `find_all` code could be changed to the following:

```
for table_data in soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'content'}):
        print(table_data)
```

And that should find something.

**Response to comments from OP:**

The precise reason why you're not finding that tag/class pairing in this case is that *DataTables* renders the table client-side via JavaScript, generally after the DOM has finished loading (although it depends on the page and where the *DataTables* init code is placed). That means the HTML associated with the base URL does not contain this content. You can see this if you `curl` the base URL and look at the output.

However when loading it in a browser, once the *JavaScript* for *DataTables* fires, the table is rendered and the DOM is dynamically modified to add the table, including cells with the class for which you're looking.

Comment: Hi Khampson, I located it under the tables section: <td class="sorting_1">Airi Satou</td>. I just realized I can't press enter when responding :P

Comment: This is what I get under "inspect element/edit HTML": <tr class="odd" role="row"><td class="sorting_1">Airi Satou</td><td>Accountant</td><td>Tokyo</td><td class=" dt-body-right">33</td><td>2008/11/28</td><td class=" dt-body-right">$162,700</td></tr>